# Achieve the correct value from one of the strings to activate windows

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to use the below batch script to activate Windows in my organization where different departments have different computer name group for different Windows keys. Unfortunately it does not work. (The batch started and closed when ran). Anyone please help me to modify it.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set group1=HR-16,DD-89,CC-05
set key1=AAAAA.BBBBB.CCCCC.DDDDD.EEEE
call :ActivateWindows %group1% %key1%

set group2=CF-05,RB-09,NO-15
set key2=BBBBB.CCCCC.DDDDD.EEEE.11111
call :ActivateWindows %group2% %key2%

set group3=AB-50,XY-23,LM-46
set key3=BBBBB.CCCCC.DDDDD.EEEE.22222
call :ActivateWindows %group3% %key3%

cscript %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs /ato

endlocal
exit /b %errorlevel%

:ActivateWindows [group] [key]
for %%G in (%~1) do for %%K in (%~2) do (
    if "%computername:~0,5%"=="%%G" if "%computername:~-2%"=="-X" (
        echo Activating Group: %%G and Key: %%K
        cscript //nologo %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs /ipk %%K
    )
)
goto :eof
```

REVISED

```
@echo off
setlocal

set group1=HR-16,DD-89,CC-05
set key1=AAAAA.BBBBB.CCCCC.DDDDD.EEEE
call :ActivateWindows "%group1%" %key1%

set group2=CF-05,RB-09,NO-15
set key2=BBBBB.CCCCC.DDDDD.EEEE.11111
call :ActivateWindows "%group2%" %key2%

set group3=AB-50,XY-23,LM-46
set key3=BBBBB.CCCCC.DDDDD.EEEE.22222
call :ActivateWindows "%group3%" %key3%

cscript %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs /ato

endlocal
exit /b %errorlevel%

:ActivateWindows [group] [key]
for %%G in (%~1) do for %%K in (%~2) do (
    if "%computername:~0,5%"=="%%G" if "%computername:~-2%"=="-X" (
        echo Activating Group: %%G and Key: %%K
        cscript //nologo %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs /ipk %%K
    )
)
goto :eof
```

Combined into one master batch to let user to choose btw manual input key and the preset key. The Input choice is fine but the Preset choice not works.

```
@echo off

REM Windows Activation
echo ================================
echo Choices:
echo. [1] = Input Key
echo. [2] = Pre-Set Key
echo ================================

goto choice


:choice
Echo ComputerName : %computername%
Choice /n /c 12 /m "Activation Choice : "%1
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" goto input
If "%errorlevel%"=="2" goto preset


:input
echo %errorlevel%

Echo Activate Windows
echo. =================================
set /p key="Input Windows KEY : "
echo. =================================

echo. %key%
echo. Press ENTER to continue if correct
pause
cscript %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs /ipk %key%
ping /n 3 localhost>nul 2>&1
cscript %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs  /ato
ping /n 3 localhost>nul 2>&1
cscript %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs /xpr
ping /n 3 localhost>nul 2>&1
goto end



:preset

set group1=HR-16,DD-89,CC-05
set key1=AAAAA.BBBBB.CCCCC.DDDDD.EEEE
call :ActivateWindows "%group1%" %key1%

set group2=CF-05,RB-09,DS-60
set key2=BBBBB.CCCCC.DDDDD.EEEE.11111
call :ActivateWindows "%group2%" %key2%

set group3=AB-50,XY-23,LM-46
set key3=BBBBB.CCCCC.DDDDD.EEEE.22222
call :ActivateWindows "%group3%" %key3%

cscript %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs /ato

endlocal
exit /b %errorlevel%

:ActivateWindows [group] [key]
for %%G in (%~1) do for %%K in (%~2) do (
    if "%computername:~0,5%"=="%%G" if "%computername:~-2%"=="-X" (
        echo Activating Group: %%G and Key: %%K
        cscript //nologo %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs /ipk %%K
    )
)
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
call :ActivateWindows "%group1%" %key1%
```

(same for 2&3)

<kbd>,</kbd> is a separator, like <kbd>Space</kbd> so the subroutine sees

`HR-16` `DD-89` `CC-05` `AAAAA.BBBBB.CCCCC.DDDDD.EEEE`

as its parameters

Comment: I followed the recommendation but it did not work also. It launched then closed without showing anything !

Comment: It seems ok but let me do more testings and revert back.

Comment: Hi, Your advice makes it works in standalone batch file. Thanks. However I want to combine the script into a batch file to let user to choose between manual input and this preset code but it does not work out then. Please review and advise where it should be modified to let it run., Thanks.